# display time from different table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm new to the site and hope someone can guide me on the right path. I'm using PostgreSQL and php. right now I need to display time start and time end. but for some reason it doesn't display right. I've read some help guides to do this but unsuccessful on that part. I have two tables with the following data.

table1

```
index   product qualityno value

   1    Mangoes aaa1      10
   2    Bananas bbb2      10
   3    Apples  ccc3      10
   4    Orange  ddd4      10
   5    Grapes  eee5      10
   6    Melons  fff6      10
   7    Lemons  ggg7      11
   8    Berry   hhh8      11
   9    Strawberry iii9   11
```

table2

```
index   qualityno   Date    Start           End

   4    ddd4         04/08/13   10:05:00 AM 11:15:00 AM
   5    eee5         04/09/13   03:11:00 PM 04:25:00 PM
   6    fff6         05/20/13   01:15:00 PM 01:30:00 PM
   7    ggg7         05/20/13   08:15:00 AM 09:10:00 AM
```

I want to display both table information within one table so I made two query without making changes on query I.

Query I

```
$sql1 =select * from table1 where value=10 or value=11
$result1 =pg_query($sql1);
```

Query II

```
$sql2 =select * from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.index = t2.index
and t1.qualityno =t2.qualityno
$result2 =pg_query($sql2);
```

I combine both by using html inside php:

```
while(($row1 =pg_fetch_array($result1)) && ($row2=pg_fetch_array($result2)))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> &nbsp; " . $row1["index"] . "</td>";
echo "<td> &nbsp; " . $row1["product"] . "</td>";
echo "<td> &nbsp; " . $row1["qualityno"] . "</td>";
echo "<td> &nbsp; " . $row1["value"] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

//I used the code below to insert the date, start and end time
//I'm hoping to print 0 if index number and qualityno no match  
//I echo  date first test my code if both index and qualityno existed.

 if(($row2[index] !=$row1[index]){ echo "<td>0</td>";}
 else{echo "<td> &nbsp; " . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>".$row2[start]."</td><td>".$row2[end]."</td>"; }
```

But every time I run the php query it doesn't match, the $row2 moves up and occupying index =1 and not inserting zero '0' making the result wrong and index is wrong.

```
index    product    qualityno   value
   1     Mangoes    aaa1    10

   4    04/08/13    10:05:00 AM 11:15:00 AM //wrong match

   2     Bananas    bbb2    10

   5    04/09/13    03:11:00 PM 04:25:00 PM //wrong match

   3    Apples  ccc3    10

   6    05/20/13    01:15:00 PM 01:30:00 PM //wrong match

   4    Orange  ddd4    10          

   5    Grapes  eee5    10

   6    Melons  fff6    10

   7    Lemons  ggg7    11
```

I want my table to display the following item below:

```
  index product    qualityno    value

   1    Mangoes      aaa1        10
          0       

   2    Bananas      bbb2        10
          0         

   3    Apples       ccc3        10
          0        

   4    Orange       ddd4        10
        04/08/13     10:05:00 AM    11:15:00 AM

   5    Grapes       eee5        10
        04/09/13     03:11:00 PM    04:25:00 PM

   6    Melons       fff6        10
        05/20/13     01:15:00 PM    01:30:00 PM

   7    Lemons       ggg7        11
         05/20/13    08:15:00 AM    09:10:00 AM

   8    Berry       hhh8         11
              0          

   9    Strawberry  iii9         11
               0         
//I was hoping that my code below can dispaly the list, 
//unfortunately its not successful

 //if(($row2[index] !=$row1[index]){ echo "<td>0</td>";}
 //else{echo "<td> &nbsp; " . $row["Date"] . "</td>"; }
```

If my description is confusing dont hesitate to ask me, please help figure this one becuse i'm quite stuck for few days now and I need help. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, coalesce(Date,'0') AS Date,coalesce(Start,'') AS Start,
       coalesce(End,'') AS End
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.index=t2.index AND t1.qualityno=t2.qualityno
```

or if you don't mind getting null values back, then it's even simpler:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Date,t2.Start,t2.End
       coalesce(End,'') AS End
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.index=t2.index AND t1.qualityno=t2.qualityno
```

Then just dump the results to a table.

Comment: thank you for the help, this made a huge difference on my goal, it works fine now...until then thank you very much!